# How to display POST value id's in their unabbreviated format in Amazon SES email using Python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-ses

I have created a web form that is submitted using `POST` method, and the data is stored in a DynamoDB table.

The `value` of the `package` id is abbreviated for more efficient storage in DynamoDB. For example, the user sees and selects an option for `Networking Package` in the web form, but this is stored in DynamoDB as `ntw`.

However, I then want to call this data and include it in an SES email template that sends a message to users, where it would display `Networking Package`, rather than `ntw`.

Here is the `html` code in the web form:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="package">Which package would you like?</label>
            <select name="package" class="form-control" id="package" required>
              <option value="">--Select--</option>
              <option value="ntw">Networking Package</option>
              <option value="drnk">Drinks Package</option>
              <option value="food">Food Package</option>
            </select>  
</div>
```

Here is my `Python` code:

```
def send_email_matched(email1, name1, email2, name2, package, client):
    senderAddress = os.environ["senderAddress"]

    response = client.send_templated_email(
        Source=senderAddress,
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                email1,
                email2
            ],
            'CcAddresses': [
                senderAddress,
            ]
        },
        Template='XXXXXXX',
        TemplateData="{\"first_name1\":\""+name1+"\", \"first_name2\":\""+name2+"\", \"package\":\""+package+"\"}"
    )
```

Is it possible to create an index (perhaps in the form of variables) for all the different package types, which when referenced in the code would then be displayed in the email, in their full unabbreviated form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED: I managed to work this out with the help of a colleague. The solution was to implement a Python dictionary in the code, where you can make the link between the abbreviated and full form of the words.

I added the dictionary values after my imports at the top of the code:

```
package_dict = {
    'ntw': 'Networking Package',
    'drnk': 'Drinks Package',
    'food': 'Food Package'
}
```

Then the function code is like so:

```
def send_email_matched(email1, name1, email2, name2, package_dict, client):
    senderAddress = os.environ["senderAddress"]

    response = client.send_templated_email(
        Source=senderAddress,
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                email1,
                email2
            ],
            'CcAddresses': [
                senderAddress,
            ]
        },
        Template='XXXXXXX',
        TemplateData="{\"first_name1\":\""+name1+"\", \"first_name2\":\""+name2+"\", \"package\":\""+package_dict+"\"}"
    )
```

Finally when calling the function:

```
send_email_matched(event["Records"][0]["dynamodb"]["NewImage"]["email_address"]["S"], first_name, package_dict[package], ses)
```

Hope this helps!